# Update a custom CursorAdapter from within itself without requery()

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I have a listView that is populated buy a custom CursorAdapter. I have a button on each row, that when clicked, toggles a value in the database and changes the icon view. The listener for that button is added in the bindView method. The problem is, when this happens the cursor is not updated, so the next time the list is redrawn (the keyboard pops up and goes away, or the list is scrolled) and the icon reverts to the original view. Because this all happens in the CursorAdapter class, I cannot reload the cursor from there, and requery is depricated. How can I trigger the cursor to be reloaded when the data changes? I don't want to go down the route of using a ContentProvider and ContentObserver for this simple task. This seems sooo basic, but I have been pouring over this site and many others, banging my head agaist a wall for literally hours on it.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        ViewHolder mvh = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

        TextView productName = mvh.name;

        productName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductsDbAdapter.KEY_PRODUCT_NAME)));


        ImageView addShoppingIcon = mvh.addShopIcon;


        //get icon state from cursor. 
        boolean isneeded = (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductsDbAdapter.KEY_PRODUCT_ISNEEDED)) == 0 ? false : true);

        //set icon tag with icon data for OnClick
        long rowid = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID));
        addShoppingIcon.setTag(new PantryHolder(rowid,inpantry,isneeded));


        //set icon bitmap
        if(isneeded)
            addShoppingIcon.setImageBitmap(MainActivity.mPantryNeedIcon);
        else
            addShoppingIcon.setImageBitmap(MainActivity.mPantryHasIcon);


        //add listener      
        addShoppingIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                PantryHolder mph = (PantryHolder)v.getTag(); 
                ImageView icon = (ImageView)v;
                if(mph.inpantry){
                    if (mph.isneeded) 
                        icon.setImageBitmap(MainActivity.mPantryHasIcon);
                    else 
                        icon.setImageBitmap(MainActivity.mPantryNeedIcon);

                } else {
                    if (mph.isneeded) 
                        icon.setImageBitmap(RealMealzActivity.mQuickAddIcon);
                    else 
                        icon.setImageBitmap(RealMealzActivity.mQuickAddGrayIcon);

                }
                mph.isneeded = !mph.isneeded;
                v.setTag(mph);
                                    //update database using database helper
                mDbAdapter.updateIsNeeded(mph.rowid, mph.isneeded);
            }
        }); 


}
```

Comment: I have built a workaround by adding: `changeCursor(mDbAdapter.fetchPantryProducts());` at the end of the onClick method... but this seems so messy. The Google doc says to do this asynchronously. There has to be another way.

Comment: You can, of course, just read the data from your DB into memory, e.g. into objects held in an *ArrayListAdapter*, then let the user modify data as he likes and afterwards persisting the changed state of your objects. - If your data does not require extreme amounts of memory (megabytes or more), that is.